Calculation of the average slope of the tractor path through the forest
I am currently working on a project whose task is to determine the average slope (in % not in absolute value but with a positive or negative sign -> rise or fall) of tractor roads located in a certain area. I have linearly recorded roads and DEM with 1 m accuracy.
Since some roads do not have a constant slope (there are ups and downs in unequal lengths, so it is impossible to set segments), I do not know how to calculate the average for each line, no matter how "long" it is, for example 2000 m or "short" for example 10 meters.
I work in QGIS.
I tried:

Calculate slope of line segments with QGIS
calculate slope of lines between nodes?

AND - QGIS plugin called Road Slope Calculator
but with not succes.
It looks like this:


You had a tag for PyQGIS but have not presented a code attempt so I removed it.

I've got a digital elevation model raster and a track vector layer.

Split line with maximum length to segmentize the lines.
Field calculate a double field, replace dem with the name of your raster layer:

100*(raster_value(layer:= @dem, band:=1, point:=end_point($geometry)) - raster_value(layer:= @dem, band:=1, point:=start_point($geometry)))/$length
The expression will extract the raster value at each segments end point and subtract the value of the segment start point and divide with the segment length, multiplied with 100 to get the segment slope in percentage.
Uphill segments get positive values, and downhill negative:

Then you can use Statistics by categories or similar to calculate average slope.

I did exactly as you wrote and it does exactly what I need...thanks for the instructions!!! I created a model and automated the work a bit. my question or problem is the following Is there a way to set the initial line file LABEL, which was created by the process Statistics on category and whose result is a table.
